# Pass string value from webform to jquery call?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, wcf, .net-4.0

I currently have a simple aspx webform that only has one div used (with div id) for a chart control. This control is populated with data from a jquery call made in file Dash.js (which is included in the aspx's HTML). When the webform loads, the jquery function `FillGraph(RunDate)` is called and the chart is displayed. Currently, I hard-code the parameter; so I call `FillGraph("20140603")`, which then invokes WCF method which is used as datasource. The following is part of the jquery function:

```
function FillGraph(RunDate) {
    ...
    dataSource: {
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: "http://localhost:50/Wcf.svc/FillChart?Date=" + RunDate,
                dataType: "json"
            }
        }
    },
```

As you can see, the function call is hard-coded with the date. If I want to change the graphic data, I'd have to go to Dash.js and change the date in FillGraph(). The JS call looks like this:

```
function FillChart() {
    FillGraph("20140603");
}

$(document).ready(FillChart);
$(document).bind("kendo:skinChange", FillChart);
```

What I'd like to do is add a textbox and a button to the ASPX. That way, when I click on the button, I take the textbox string and somehow pass it to the jquery call.

I didn't post any code because there is none. I just want to know how to send a value from a webform to a jquery function call that's in a separate .JS file. I tried googling it, but I don't think I'm searching correctly.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your button and textbox are ASP.NET controls btnFillChart and txtDateString respectively, set the button client click handler:

```
OnClientClick="FillChart();return false"
```

Then replace your hard-coded date in `FillChart` with:

```
$('#<%=txtDateString.ClientID%>').val()
```

Comment: Thanks. I added the clien click handler to FillChart() and it calls the function. But I then added `alert($('#<%=txtDateString.ClientID%>').val());` but it doesn't display the popup.

Comment: This is what my function looks like:  `function FillCharts() { alert('FillCharts Called'); alert($('#<%=txtDateString.ClientID%>').val()); }`

Comment: It should be used like this: `alert($("#txtDateString").val());`